# What is the best way to divide two TimeSpan objects?

Tags: c#

I want to get the ratio of one TimeSpan against another TimeSpan (Basically the progress of a playing video from it's total time).  My current methods is to get the milliseconds of the two TimeSpan objects and divide one against the other. Something like:

```
        int durationInMilliseconds = totalTimeSpan.Milliseconds;
        int progressInMilliseconds = progressTimeSpan.Milliseconds;

        Double progressRatio = progressInMilliseconds / durationInMilliseconds;
```

Is there a more direct route?  It's a simple problem and i'm just curious if there is a super elegant way to solve it.

Cheers all
James

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use either [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(loband).aspx) or [TotalMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds(loband).aspx), depending on the required precision. [Milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds(loband).aspx) is the number of milliseconds past the current second.

As for a better solution, it doesn't get simpler than a division so your current solution is fine (minus the bug).

Comment: @Richard Szalay gets the answer as i know he posted the solution first.

Answer (score 19):

```
double progressRatio = progressTimeSpan.Ticks / (double)totalTimeSpan.Ticks;
```

You must cast one to a double, otherwise C# will do integer division. Ticks is better than the TotalMilliseconds because that is how it is stored and avoids any conversion.

Comment: @JDunkerley: The conversion issue is irrelevant: You're calling `Ticks` and then converting to `double` yourself. Calling `TotalMilliseconds` just means that the conversion to `double` is done within the method instead. `Ticks` has greater accuracy than `TotalMilliseconds`, and that's often a good reason to use it, but pretty-much irrelevant in this case where we're just calculating a ratio.

Comment: I meant that the TimeSpan is stored in Ticks and would need to be converted into MilliSeconds first before being returned to the function. Admittedly this is a very fast operation and the cost of this calculation is basically zero, but it is more efficient to divide the Tick rather than converting to ms and dividing those.

Comment: @JDunkerley: I've just ran some quick benchmarks here and there is *no measurable difference at all* between the two techniques. They're both managing roughly 25 million iterations per second, and they're always neck-and-neck even after running tens of billions of iterations.

Answer (score 3):

`TimeSpan` gained several new operators with the release of **.NET Core 2.0**:

```
public TimeSpan Divide(double divisor);
public double Divide(TimeSpan ts);
public TimeSpan Multiply(double factor);

public static TimeSpan operator /(TimeSpan timeSpan, double divisor);
public static double operator /(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2);
public static TimeSpan operator *(double factor, TimeSpan timeSpan);
public static TimeSpan operator *(TimeSpan timeSpan, double factor);
```

Of note, a `TimeSpan` can now be divided by another `TimeSpan`:

```
var a = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0);
var b = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
var c = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 30);

Console.WriteLine(a / b);
// Displays: "20"

Console.WriteLine(b / c);
// Displays: "6.66666666666667"
```

Comment: Shame it's not yet available in .NET Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of extension method can make codes more readable.

```
public static double DividedBy(this TimeSpan x, TimeSpan y)
{
    return Convert.ToDouble(x.Ticks) / y.Ticks;
}
```